# Counting Max Consecutive Zero Values - trying not to count blank cells but ISNUMBER isn't working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the max number of times zero appears in a row.  This formula works for that, however it is including blank cells as zeros.  I am trying to avoid that by using ISNUMBER,  but when I include ISNUMBER the formula returns 0, which is incorrect.  Can anyone help?

Thanks so much!

=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(H3:AL3=0, COLUMN(H3:AL3)), IF(H3:AL3<>0, COLUMN(H3:AL3))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add IF()+ISNUMBER() to your formula in ignore blank cells, as in :

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(IF(ISNUMBER(H3:AL3),H3:AL3,"")=0,COLUMN(H3:AL3)),IF(IF(ISNUMBER(H3:AL3),H3:AL3,"")<>0,COLUMN(H3:AL3))))
```

This is an array (CSE) formula, confirmed by pressing "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" to entry.